# No connection between Nintendo Switch and PC on custom cable

Tags: usb, usb-c

I had a USB A -> USB A (3.0-) cable and out of concern I might damage something if I don't use it with the cheap capture card it came with, I cut one end off and replaced it with a USB C connector. I plugged the C-end of the cable in to my PC and when I use a USB A (female) -> USB C (male) adapter to connect my Switch with it to my PC, it  isn't recognized. It doesn't even appear to get power.

I can use a micro USB adapter to connect my phone with this to my PC and if i use the male USB A 3.0 on my capture card I can use it as well. The USB C connector also works. For example, I can connect a USB thumbdrive with it to my PC or Switch.

I tried to make a diagram in paint (please note that all the connection lines are the same cable with either no or different adapters on the USB A side. They are shown in the same picture for the reason to keep it simple. The different connections can not occur at the same time):

[image]

Comment: That's not going to work. Get a new cable, one with usb C connectors on both ends.

Comment: is there a way to set one side up as master or as slave?

Comment: The devices themselves will decide who is master and who is slave.

Comment: damm it. i thought this might be similar possible as the resistor part on a breakout board  for usb c

Comment: How is that supposed to do anything? You did not even state how you wired the connectors.

Comment: In regards to the wireing: i connected them without switching anything. red to red, black to black, green to green and so on.

Well in case of PD, they set one end as the reciever for 5v input. So i thought there may be something similar for data too.

Comment: With an USb C to C wire, do not use resistors, instead wire, VBUS, GND, D-, D+ and CC straight from one side to the other. Resistors are only used in legacy cables. Also, show in your diagrams how you wired up the CC pins